# Draw image layer in tmx map - libgdx

Tags: libgdx, tiled

I created a map only with an image layer in tiled map editor.

[image: Only an image layer]
[image: settings]

When I want to load the map the layer isn't shown. Only the background color.

[image]

Followed the tutorial from 
http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/04/16/LibGDX-Tutorial-11-Tiled-Maps-Part-1-Simple-Orthogonal-Maps.aspx

Here the code (left out empty overrides):

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;

public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor  {
TiledMap tiledMap;
OrthographicCamera camera;
TiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;

@Override
public void create () {
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false,w,h);
    camera.update();
    tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("C:/Users/Robin/Desktop/map.tmx");
    tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();
    tiledMapRenderer.setView(camera);
    tiledMapRenderer.render();
}
}
```

I added a tileset and tried again (just a little test). Only the tiles are visible:
[image: red marked the part you can see]
[image: view in opengl - libgdx]

Any ideas how to set the layer visible?

Greetings 
Kaito

Comment: Tell us what you've tried and how it's not working. Edit your question to include the information, the link to the tutorial you're following can go bad making this question not useful to future visitors.

Comment: added screenshots and code for better understanding

Answer (score 3):

When browsing the libgdx documentation (for example at http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/MapLayer.html), I don't see any mention of the image layer, so most likely this relatively new (and still quite limited) layer type is not supported by libgdx yet.

If you would like to see this supported in libgdx, I suggest opening an issue about it at https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues

*Update: This feature has been implemented in libgdx in the meantime. See https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/2741*